# Continue execution after exception handling

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am writing a script to execute multiple unique queries (which cannot be placed in a loop). On adding Exception handler, as soon as the first Error occurs, the exception is handled but the compiler exits the block and terminates the program.

How do I get my program to handle the exception and continue executing the next query?

Below is the code I have been working on:

```
DECLARE
  NEW_VAR1 VARCHAR2(20000);
  table_does_not_exist exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -942);
BEGIN
  DBMS_output.put_line('Query 1 Execution');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN
    SELECT "defaultpwd" INTO :out1 from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and substr(spare4,3,40)=rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw("oracle")||hextoraw(substr(spare4,43,20)), 3))) UNION SELECT "defaultpwd" from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and password="EE7785338B8FFE3D";
  END;'
  USING out NEW_VAR1;
  DBMS_output.put_line(NEW_VAR1);

  DBMS_output.put_line('Query 2 Execution');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN
    SELECT "defaultpwd" INTO :out2 from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and substr(spare4,3,40)=rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw("oracle")||hextoraw(substr(spare4,43,20)), 3))) UNION SELECT "defaultpwd" from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and password="EE7785338B8FFE3D";
  END;'
  USING out NEW_VAR1;
  DBMS_output.put_line(NEW_VAR1);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
    DBMS_output.put_line('Table does not exist!!');
  WHEN others then
    DBMS_output.put_line('Error!!');
END;
```

The Desired outcome in this case would be:

```
Query 1 Execution
Error!!
Query 2 Execution
Error!!
```

The Actual Outcome is:

```
Query 1 Execution
Error!!
```

I am open to alternate ways to execute multiple distinct queries if the above mentioned code is not efficient.

Comment: You need separate `BEGIN...EXCEPTION...END`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have different exception blocks for each query. Something like this:

```
    DECLARE
      NEW_VAR1 VARCHAR2(20000);
      table_does_not_exist exception;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -942);
    BEGIN
      BEGIN
          DBMS_output.put_line('Query 1 Execution');
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN
            SELECT "defaultpwd" INTO :out1 from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and    substr(spare4,3,40)=rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw("oracle")||hextoraw(substr(spare4,43,20)), 3))) UNION SELECT "defaultpwd" from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and password="EE7785338B8FFE3D";
          END;'
          USING out NEW_VAR1;
          DBMS_output.put_line(NEW_VAR1);
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
              DBMS_output.put_line('Table does not exist!!');
          WHEN others then
              DBMS_output.put_line('Error!!');
      END;

      BEGIN
          DBMS_output.put_line('Query 2 Execution');
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN
            SELECT "defaultpwd" INTO :out2 from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and substr(spare4,3,40)=rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw("oracle")||hextoraw(substr(spare4,43,20)), 3))) UNION SELECT "defaultpwd" from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and password="EE7785338B8FFE3D";
          END;'
          USING out NEW_VAR1;
          DBMS_output.put_line(NEW_VAR1);
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
              DBMS_output.put_line('Table does not exist!!');
          WHEN others then
              DBMS_output.put_line('Error!!');
      END;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle you have to do it like this:

```
DECLARE
  NEW_VAR1 VARCHAR2(20000);
  table_does_not_exist exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -942);
BEGIN

BEGIN
  DBMS_output.put_line('Query 1 Execution');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN
    SELECT "defaultpwd" INTO :out1 from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and substr(spare4,3,40)=rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw("oracle")||hextoraw(substr(spare4,43,20)), 3))) UNION SELECT "defaultpwd" from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and password="EE7785338B8FFE3D";
  END;'
  USING out NEW_VAR1;
  DBMS_output.put_line(NEW_VAR1);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
    DBMS_output.put_line('Table does not exist!!');
  WHEN others then
    DBMS_output.put_line('Error!!');
END;

BEGIN
  DBMS_output.put_line('Query 2 Execution');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN
    SELECT "defaultpwd" INTO :out2 from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and substr(spare4,3,40)=rawtohex(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw("oracle")||hextoraw(substr(spare4,43,20)), 3))) UNION SELECT "defaultpwd" from sys.user$ where name="APEX_040000" and password="EE7785338B8FFE3D";
  END;'
  USING out NEW_VAR1;
  DBMS_output.put_line(NEW_VAR1);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
    DBMS_output.put_line('Table does not exist!!');
  WHEN others then
    DBMS_output.put_line('Error!!');
END;

END;
```

Or put it in a loop:

```
BEGIN

FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
  BEGIN
    DBMS_output.put_line('Query '||i||' Execution');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ...

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN
      DBMS_output.put_line('Table does not exist!!');
    WHEN others then
      DBMS_output.put_line('Error!!');
  END;
END LOOP;

END;
```

However your code has several errors/flaws:

- Why do you run two times exactly the same query?
- `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` requires exactly **one** row to be returned. Due to `UNION` this is rather unlikely.
- The code must be like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ... FROM ...' INTO NEW_VAR1;`
- I don't think table `sys.user$` has any column `defaultpwd` (in lower case)
- you should use `WHEN others then DBMS_output.put_line('Error!!' || SQLERRM);` in order to see the actual error, otherwise you hide it. That's even worse as you are a beginner in SQL
- What is the purpose of your query, it does not make much sense to me. If you like to compare with `PASSWORD` make simple `=` or `<>`
- Even if your query would work, there is no reason for dynamic SQL. Use simple `SELECT ... INTO NEW_VAR1 FROM ...`. The `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for dynamic SQL? There's nothing *dynamic* in queries you run.

What is *worse*, is that those selects use `UNION` which mean that they'll possibly return two or more rows into a scalar variable, and that won't work.

Furthermore, you misused `INTO` clause.

This is something like what you're doing now (example is based on Scott's schema):

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate
  5    q'[select deptno into :out1
  6      from emp
  7      where ename = 'SCOTT'
  8     union
  9     select deptno into :out2
 10       from dept
 11       where dname = 'ACCOUNTING']'
 12    using out l_result;
 13
 14    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
 15  end;
 16  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO
ORA-06512: at line 4


SQL>
```

If you fix it, you get the *worse* thing: `too_many_rows` as you're returning 2 rows into a single `varchar2` variable:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate
  5    q'[select deptno
  6      from emp
  7      where ename = 'SCOTT'
  8     union
  9     select deptno
 10       from dept
 11       where dname = 'ACCOUNTING']'
 12    into l_result;
 13
 14    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
 15  end;
 16  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

As there's nothing dynamic in it, switch to pure `select` (will return `too_many_rows` again, of course):

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    select deptno
  5      into l_result
  6      from (select deptno
  7              from emp
  8              where ename = 'SCOTT'
  9            union
 10            select deptno
 11              from dept
 12              where dname = 'ACCOUNTING'
 13           );
 14
 15    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
 16  end;
 17  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Finally, use appropriate variable, an array:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result sys.odcivarchar2list;
  3  begin
  4    select deptno
  5      bulk collect into l_result
  6      from (select deptno
  7              from emp
  8              where ename = 'SCOTT'
  9            union
 10            select deptno
 11              from dept
 12              where dname = 'ACCOUNTING'
 13           );
 14
 15    for i in l_result.first .. l_result.last loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line(l_result(i));
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /
10
20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

As of errors you encounter: as you were already told, you need to enclose every statement into its own begin-exception-end block. Something like this simplified example ("simplified" means that you should handle exceptions properly. Don't use WHEN OTHERS just because it exists; you'd rather let the error happen, recognize it and handle properly):

```
declare
  l_result sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  -- start of the first inner begin-exception-end block
  begin
    select deptno
      bulk collect into l_result
      from (select deptno
              from emp
              where ename = 'SCOTT'
            union 
            select deptno
              from dept
              where dname = 'ACCOUNTING'
           );

    for i in l_result.first .. l_result.last loop
      dbms_output.put_line(l_result(i));
    end loop;  
  exception
    when others then
      dbms_output.put_Line('handle it');
  end;
  -- end of the first inner begin-exception-end block

  -- start of the second inner begin-exception-end block
  begin
    null;
  exception
    when others then null;
  end;
  -- end of the second inner begin-exception-end block
end;
/
```